# Convert EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy to YYYY-MM-dd JAVA

Tags: java, date, format

I want to convert : `Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 WET 2012` to `02/02/2012` (with date type not string) using JAVA.

I did

```
String date = "Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 WET 2012";
SimpleDateFormat formatnow = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH); 
SimpleDateFormat formatneeded=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
Date date1 = formatnow.parse(date);
String date2 = formatneeded.format(date1);
Date date3= formatneeded.parse(date2);
System.out.println(date3);
```

And I'm having : `Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 WET 2012`.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem ??

Comment: what does `System.out.println(date2);` give you?

Comment: It gives me : Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 WET 2012

Comment: Sorry date2 gives me: 2012-02-02 but i dont want as string type i want date type to store in my database

Comment: A date does not have any formatting associated with it,so simply store `date1` in your DB.

Comment: Date uses `toString` method to represent its value, and this method returns format you see as output. That is why where is SimpleDateFormat class which lets you produce `String` with desired format.

Answer (score 1):

The Date object does not hold any information about the display format you want. So parsing a date from a formatted date string is not going to 'remember' any formatting.

System.out.println(date3) will print value of date3 using java's toString method.

You have the formatted date string in date2. So System.out.println(date2) should give you the right value.